# R 複数要素の数列の件

Tags: r

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(2:11)
```

`x + y`はできるのに`x : y`だとエラーが出てしまいます。

複数の数列を作成したいのですが、どうしても一つしか認識されません。
このような数列を作成できる関数等ご存知でしたら教えて頂けると幸いです。
お忙しいところ大変恐縮ですが、どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

`purrr`パッケージの`map2`関数の例です。

```
x<-c(1:3)
y<-c(2:4)

library(purrr)
map2(.x = x, .y = y, .f = `:`)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速使用してみます。